# C Programming - Move to the next line in a text file using file handling functions

Tags: c, file-handling

I have a text file contains a 4 words ; each one in a line , which function allows me to control the lines ; like i want to read the first line only and after move to the next line ( equivalent to \n in console) and store each one in a string

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets

Comment: very helpful thanks !

Comment: Be careful as `fgets` wont work if your line is longer than allocated memory for `fgets`.

Comment: thanks for information ; and i will add something : char* fgets (char*, int c, FILE*); // always pass the argument to the int c : ( sizeof line ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major functions that read input line-by-line:

- If you have a pre-allocated buffer, use `fgets`.
- If you want the buffer allocated for you, use `getline` (note that it only conforms to POSIX 2008 and above).

## Using `fgets`

```c
#include <stdio.h> // fgets
FILE *f = stdin;

char buf[4096]; // static buffer of some arbitrary size.
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f) == buf) {
    // If a newline is read, it would be at the end of the buffer. The newline may not be read if fgets() reaches the buffer limit, or if EOF is reached, or if reading the file is interrupted.
    printf("Text: %s\n", buf);
}
```

## Using `getline`

```c
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 200809L // getline is not standard ISO C, but rather part of POSIX.
#include <stdio.h> // getline
#include <stdlib.h> // free

FILE *f = stdin;
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t nread;

while (nread = getline(&line, &len, f)) != 1) {
    // Note that the newline \n is always stored unless it reached EOF first.
    // len stores the current length of the buffer, and nread stores the length of the current string in the buffer. getline() grows the buffer for you whenever it needs to.
    printf("New line read: %s", line);
}

// It's the programmer's job to free() the buffer that getline() has allocated
free(line);
```

Comment: You forgot: "if you want maximal performance&flexibility: use getc() and a state machine".

Comment: free(line) can be used for stack data buffer ?

Comment: Returning `NULL` from `strchr(buf, '\n')` doesn't necessarily indicate *"Part of very large line read: "*. It is also possible that the stream doesn't end with a `'\n'`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Right, my mistake, I edited the example code so it doesn't try to do anything smart with the newline.

Comment: OP probably also wants to remove the newline character from the input. In that case, this question will also be relevant: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471)